# What font is used by Google Chrome on its user interface?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I would like to know the name of the font use by Google Chrome on its user interface, not on its web pages.

This is some parts of that uses the font I would like to know the name:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the great things about Chrome is pretty much everything is built with HTML/JavaScript, so you can just use the developer tools in Chrome to find out.

Unfortunately you can't in with the developer tools, but assuming that the settings page uses the same font (which it looks like it does), you can just right click anywhere in the settings, and select "Inspect Element", and then look at the CSS applied to the element to see which font is being used.  In my browser the font being used is **Segoe UI**.

Comment: ...which is the default font in the Windows GUI since Windows Vista, IIRC.

Comment: To inspect the Developer Tools, undock them, then hit Ctrl+Shift+I. A new instance of the Developer Tools will open to inspect the existing Developer Tools window.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome uses a stylesheet to define everything within the Developer Tools Panel.

This stylesheet is located:

- Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/
- PC:  \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css
- Ubuntu:  ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets

On a side note, I love customizing this to have dev tools the same theme as my IDE, terminal/console etc. There are plenty of stylesheets already set up using some of your favourite colour schemes.

Here's a couple:

- [Tomorrow Theme](https://gist.github.com/bentruyman/1163300)
- [Monokai Theme](https://github.com/anilkabobo/MonokaiThemeForChrome/blob/master/Custom.css)

Check out [Dev Themez](http://devthemez.com/) for a huge collection.